# Calculate distance from a static camera to an object on a ground plane

Tags: matrix, camera, coordinates, distance, projection

I have a stationary camera, which is 640mm above the ground and is tilted slightly forward (about the x-axis?) roughly 30 degrees, so it's looking slightly down towards a flat ground plane.

My goal is to ***determine the distance from the camera to any small objects that it detects on the ground***, for example, if my camera detects an object which is located at pixel [314, 203], I would like to know where on the ground that object would be in world coordinates [x, y, z] with y=0, and the distance to that object.

I've drawn a diagram to better visualize the problem:
[camera plane diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4hOl.jpg)

I have my rotation matrix and translation vector and also my intrinsic matrix, but I'm not sure 1) if the rotation matrix and translation vector are correct given the information/diagram above, and 2) how to proceed with figuring out a mathematical formula for finding distance and real world location. Here is what I have so far:

Rotation matrix R (generated here https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/) from the orientation [-30, 0, 0] (degrees) 
**R = 

[  1.0000000,  0.0000000,  0.0000000;

0.0000000,  0.8660254,  -0.5000000;

0.0000000, 0.5000000,  0.8660254 ]**

Camera is 640mm above ground plane 
**t = 

[0, 640, 0]**

Intrinsic matrix from calibration information given by camera 
fx=349.595, fy=349.505, cx=328.875, cy=178.204 
**K = 

[ 349.595, 0.0000, 328.875;

0.0000, 349.505, 178.204;

0.0000, 0.0000,  1.000 ]**

I also have these distortion parameters, I'm unsure what to do with them or if they are relevant to **K**
**k1=-0.170901, k2=0.0255027, k3=-9.30328e-11, p1=0.000117187, p2=6.42836e-05**

I get about this far and then I'm lost, any help would be much appreciated.
Also sorry if this is a lot of information or if it's confusing in any way, I'm very much a beginner when it comes to projection matrices

**UPDATE:**

After some more research and testing on my own I found a formula that *seems* to give me a somewhat decent approximation. Given pixel [x, y], I find ***(I think)*** the direction vector from the camera origin to the pixel coordinate with:

dir_x = (x - cx) / fx

dir_y = (y - cy) / fy

dir_z = 1

which I then multiply by rotation matrix R, which gives me the real-world vector. I then divide my camera height (640mm) by the y-value of that vector, which gives me ***(I think)*** the distance to the specified pixel in the real-world. After some testing and measuring by hand, this seems to be an adequate method for finding the distance, but I'm not sure if I'm missing steps for accuracy or if I'm actually doing this completely wrong.

Again, any insight is greatly appreciated.